# DragStarted event is not getting in UWP Slider - c#

Tags: c#, uwp, slider

I want to change the video position according to how much I drag the slider. So that I want to use DragStarted and DragCompleted events. But it shows "The local property 'Dragstarted' can only be applied to types that are derived from 'Thumb'". How can I include it in my app?

```
 <Slider Name="timelineSlider" Thumb.DragCompleted= "timelineSlider_DragCompleted" DragStarting="timelineSlider_DragStarting" DragOver="timelineSlider_DragOver" Width="300" />
```

Also found that there is DragStarting and DragOver events. Does it have the same functionality of  Dragstarted and DragCompleted events? Unfortuantely DragStarting and DragOver events are not firing when I drag the slider.

Comment: You may think of using [PointerCaptureLost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_PointerCaptureLost).

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [ManipulationStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationStarted) and [ManipulationCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationCompleted) event of the [Slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/slider).

```
 <Slider ManipulationCompleted="Slider_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationStarted="Slider_ManipulationStarted"/>
```

You must set the [ManipulationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_ManipulationMode) to a value other than **System** or **None** if you want to handle manipulation events such as ManipulationStarted from UI elements in your app code.

```
private void Slider_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var slide= sender as Slider;
    Debug.WriteLine(slide.GetType().ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(slide.Value+ ">>Slider_ManipulationCompleted");
}

private void Slider_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var slide = sender as Slider;
    Debug.WriteLine(slide.GetType().ToString());
    Debug.WriteLine(slide.Value+ "Slider_ManipulationStarted");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PointerCaptureLost` works well in UWP App.

Examle XAML:

```
<Slider x:Name="SeekSlider" PointerCaptureLost="SeekSlider_PointerCaptureLost"/>
```

Example C#:

```
private void SeekSlider_PointerCaptureLost(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Slider slider = sender as Slider;
    if (slider != null)
    {
        //mediaPlayer.Position = (float)slider.Value;
    }
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can more easily use the `ValueChanged` event to see the changes in the position of the `Slider`:

```
<Slider x:Name="Slider" ValueChanged="Slider_OnValueChanged" />
```

You can use the `e.NewValue` to get the new value of the slider and the `e.OldValue` to get the previous position.

```
private void Slider_OnValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Slider moved from {e.OldValue} to {e.NewValue}");
}
```

Comment: no ValueChanged event will not  meet my requirement since it calls every time slider changes its value. even if video playing. I just want to call the event while dragging on slider only.

Comment: In that case you could probably use the VisualTreeHelper from UWP Community Toolkit to access the Slider's Thumb and hook up the DragStarted and DragEnded events, that would set just a flag which would say that user is interacting and the ValueChanged event is cause by the user

Comment: What I used in one of my apps: Focuslost event...@Martin: can you send a link to the VisualTreeHelper? I can't found it in th UWP Community Toolkit App

Comment: I was wrong about the name - it is VisualTreeExtensions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree